# Get Resolution in Windows 8.1 Universal

Tags: c#, windows-8.1-universal

I searched a lot for finding resolution of my Windows 8.1 Universal app.
I know that we can get height and width of screen with:

```
var screenHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
var screenWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```

But It isn't resolution. I want to get value "1366*768" or "1920*1080".   I know about ResolutionScale too:

```
var scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ResolutionScale;
```

It return for me always 100%. It doesn't help me to convert width and height to screen resolution. I need to get resolution in **Windows 8.1 Universal**. It's very important for me.
so  If I can't get screen resolution in windows 8.1 universal, so How can I scale fonts for different screen resolution. What are other company programmers do for this problem?
Is it possible to help me?
I'm sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pixels per logical inch this way:

```
 double dpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawDpiY;
```

it gets the raw dots per inch (DPI) along the y axis of the display monitor and will return 0 if you have two displays in duplicate mode.

To get phisical screen size you can use:

```
double screenDiagonal = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(screenWidth / dpi, 2) + Math.Pow(screenHeight / dpi, 2));
```

to get pixels try this:

```
var scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
double w=screenWidth*scaleFactor;
double h=screenheight*scaleFactor;
```

That's for WP8.1 and UWP. For Windows 8.1 Store  Apps try ResolutionScale:

```
ResolutionScale resolutionScale = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ResolutionScale;
double scaleFactor = (double)resolutionScale / 100.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The thing that I need something like scaleFactor But it only works for windows phone 8.1. How can I convert screenDiagonal to resolution like this: "1366*768"? Is it possible to help me?

Comment: for windows store apps try to use ResolutionScale

Comment: How can I use ResolutionScale. It returns 100% for me. it means 100/100 = 1 so I have to double w = screenWidth * 1; But It doesn't true. It doesn't return my screen resolution?! I use it true or not?

Comment: Screen resolution 1920x1080 on small 5 inch phone and on large notebook 23 inch screen is not same. You'll get different Window.Current.Bounds.Height and Width on defferent devices with same resolution. Resolution Scale is percent that resizes screen resolution for better view depend of physical screen size

Comment: take a look at this link [Obtaining screen resolution scale details in Windows 8 Metro Style App](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/obtaining-screen-resolution-scale-details-in-windows-8-metro-style-app) or at this [Detecting screen resolution in Windows 8 and Windows Phone apps](https://programmerpayback.com/2013/08/31/detecting-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-and-windows-phone-apps/)